# How to hide matching lines in Kdiff3

Tags: diff, kdiff3

Does anyone know of a way to **hide matching lines** in Kdiff3 (in Windows). I really only care about the differences and would rather quickly scroll through that list of differences without all the just filler (i.e. matching lines) in between.

I'm open to other software options but I find it hard to believe Kdiff3 doesn't have this functionality.

Comment: I still can't find this option either. The next best software for comparing I know of is Beyond Compare, though it does cost money :-\

Comment: Why it has to be Kdiff3? There are enough other (free) tools for comparision (WinMerge, BC, ...(). And why not using git with its diff algorithm?

Comment: Kdiff3 is well optimised and is able to compare very long files where e.g. Meld is hanging.